# Oracle sql in NetSuite

Tags: type-conversion, netsuite, to-date

I am trying to convert Jan 2017 to a date of 1/1/2017 and I am hitting so many roadblocks.  I can get it to be a text value of '1/1/2017' with a `{formula}` but when I try to do `to_date({formula},'MM/DD/YYYY')` it just gives an error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the ***exact*** error you are getting.  Otherwise, we are as lost as you are.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking for...  But, why not use the NetSuite String to Date function?  If you are trying to write to a date field in NetSuite, that function will provide you with the date that you are looking for.

```
var startDate={formula}; //No idea what your formula is.  But, you said this returns 1/1/2017;
var newDate=nlapiStringToDate(startDate);
```

[NetSuite Date APIs](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10250#bridgehead_N3061544)